# Chrome bookmark virus

Tags: google-chrome, virus

I am getting re-directs with 'webhp' something like:

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=div+with+arrow+css&start=10

I also notice that my Google Chrome Bookmark star looks differently and when I click on it I get:

I guess I can't post images...It is a strange bookmark pop-up when I click on the star.

Is this a virus and how do I get back to my old bookmark star?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bookmark Star

Only this could cause the changing of the bookmark star

- Chrome update (new version with new UI)

Shortly my answer is No:

- because I don't think a malware is not being involved with changing the bookmark star of your browser
- A trojan and other virus is designed to steal data on the PC or to weeken your computer

You can get the bookmark star back with maybe a downgrading If it's relly caused by an update

### Re-directs

It could be a Toolbar.
With Toolbar, I don't mean the one with the tools on your browser, I mean the ones like the default page changers like:

- Ask toolbar
- Yontoo toolbar
- Babylon toolbar

Not all of them are malicious, some of them come with installations like adwares

Comment: Thanks, very informative.  If it is a toolbar, how would one go about getting rid of it.  I checked other computers with the same version of Chrome, and the bookmark star and function does not operate the way mine is :(.  I checked the Extensions, but all are disabled.  Any help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: You can get rid of it by installing Malwarebytes or other spyware removal tools. Of course toolbar term is not the same as spyware, but the difference between spyware and toolbar is: Toolbars are rather annoying than malicious, spywares are trying to spy you. But the spyware removal tools are different from antiviruses. They dont have realtime protection, but good for scanning. I suggest these anti spyware tools:          Malware bytes, Spyware terminator, Spybot search & Destroy 1(that's one of the best, found some toolbars on my computer). And sorry for the late reply